# Using a function in R with multiple outcomes to create multiple columns in mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using a self declared function that runs a regression analysis. I want to run this for thousands of companies for multiple years, thus speed is essential. My function creates three outputs (a coefficient, the p value and r-squared). The function runs fine individually, however when I use mutate() to let it run through the whole dataset, it only gives the same values for all rows. The weirdest thing is that I can't reproduce those particular values by running the function individually. I made an reproducible example below. I have used lapply successfully before with this data, but I would like to keep it in mutate and above all I would like to know what's exactly happening here.

So my question is: how can I make this function work for each individual row for the companies dataset using mutate?

```
library(tidyverse)

companies <- data.frame(comp_id = 1:5)
individuals <- data.frame(id = 1:100, 
                          comp_id = sample(1:5, 100, replace = T),
                          age = sample(18:67, 100, replace = T),
                          wage = sample(1700:10000, 100, replace = T))

regger <- function(x){
  df <- individuals %>% filter(comp_id == x)
  formula <- wage ~ age
  regression <- lm(formula, df)
  
  res <- list(coeff = summary(regression)$coefficient[2,1], 
              p = summary(regression)$coefficients[2,4], 
              r2 = summary(regression)$r.squared)
  return(res)
}

companies %>% 
  mutate(data = list(regger(comp_id))) %>%
  unnest_wider(data)
```

output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  comp_id coeff     p       r2
    <int> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1       1 -4.92 0.916 0.000666
2       2 -4.92 0.916 0.000666
3       3 -4.92 0.916 0.000666
4       4 -4.92 0.916 0.000666
5       5 -4.92 0.916 0.000666
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use map from the purrr package if a function is not vectorized:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1337)
companies <- data.frame(comp_id = 1:5)
individuals <- data.frame(
  id = 1:100,
  comp_id = sample(1:5, 100, replace = T),
  age = sample(18:67, 100, replace = T),
  wage = sample(1700:10000, 100, replace = T)
)

regger <- function(x) {
  df <- individuals %>% filter(comp_id == x)
  formula <- wage ~ age
  regression <- lm(formula, df)

  res <- list(
    coeff = summary(regression)$coefficient[2, 1],
    p = summary(regression)$coefficients[2, 4],
    r2 = summary(regression)$r.squared
  )
  return(res)
}

companies %>%
  mutate(data = comp_id %>% map(regger)) %>%
  unnest_wider(data)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   comp_id  coeff     p         r2
#>     <int>  <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1       1 67.1   0.108 0.218     
#> 2       2 23.7   0.466 0.0337    
#> 3       3 31.2   0.292 0.0462    
#> 4       4 18.4   0.582 0.0134    
#> 5       5  0.407 0.994 0.00000371
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the output should look like, but could it be that you need to work on a row-by-row basis?

```
companies %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(data = list(regger(comp_id))) %>%
  unnest_wider(data)

  comp_id  coeff     p        r2
    <int>  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1       1 21.6   0.470 0.0264   
2       2 13.5   0.782 0.00390  
3       3  0.593 0.984 0.0000175
4       4 -9.33  0.824 0.00394  
5       5 64.9   0.145 0.156
```